# WordPress MU for hosting subdirectories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to consolidate two WordPress installations into one WP MU install.

Basically, I have example.com/blog and example.com/microsite/blog

I'd like the microsite's blog and the /blog to both be hosted by WordPress MU. Does sunrise help me accomplish this? If not, how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to accept an answer by clicking the check mark when you are satisfied with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impending WordPress 3.0 release changes the calculation of this question. In one month, May 2010, WordPress 3.0 will merge the Core and MU versions together. Here is a quote:

> The merge! Yes, WordPress and WordPress MU have merged. This does not mean that you can suddenly start adding a bunch of new blogs from within your regular WordPress Dashboard. If you’re interested in testing the Super Admin stuff associated with multiple sites, you’ll need some simple directions to get started.

http://wordpress.org/development/2010/04/wordpress-3-0-beta-1/

And directions on how to create a "Network"
http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Andrea/Create_A_Network

I suggest you spend your effort on porting your existing themes and custom code to the new 3.0 version because the general community of plugins and themes will evolve with 3.0 and anyone not upgrading will eventually be left behind.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I'll start investigating...